# Python OpenCV / PIL COLOR_BGR2RGB Error

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I've written some Python code that takes frames from a video and puts several of them into rows/columns in jpegs. For the most part, it works, except for the end. So I assume this error has something to do with indexing out-of-range in an array.

```
import cv2, Image, os


name = raw_input('Video File (With Extension): ')
x_res = int(raw_input('Image Width (Pixels): '))
y_res = int(raw_input('Image Height (Pixels): '))
rows = int(raw_input('Number of Rows: '))
columns = int(raw_input('Number of Columns: '))


vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
_,im = vidcap.read()
frames = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_res, y_res))
x_cntr = 0
y_cntr = 0


if not os.path.exists('./' + name + ' Output/'):
    os.makedirs('./' + name + ' Output/')


for x in xrange(0,frames,1):
    if x%(rows*columns) == 0:
        new_im.save('./' + name + ' Output/' + str(x) + '.jpg')
        new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_res,y_res))
        y_cntr = 0
        x_cntr = 0
        print str(round(100*(float(x)/frames), 1)) + "% Complete"
    elif x%rows == 0:
        x_cntr = 0
        y_cntr = y_cntr + y_res/columns
    elif x%1 == 0:
        x_cntr = x_cntr + x_res/rows
    _,cv2_im = vidcap.read()
    cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    im = Image.fromarray(cv2_im)
    im = im.resize((x_res/rows + x_res%rows, y_res/columns + y_res%columns), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    new_im.paste(im, (x_cntr, y_cntr))
```

It returns this when it is going to make the last image:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cameron/Downloads/JPG/IMG2.py", line 36, in <module>
    cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:7349: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Comment: Image from vidcap seems to be grayscale. Check the number of channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, it was trying to save a non-existent frame to the end. So if I chose 5 rows and 5 columns, when there were 132 frames, it wouldn't divide equally (132 % 25 ≠ 0) and it would try to index something out of range of the video. So I basically added an "if success == True" then process normally, else "if success == False" then save what it has and stop. So here is the working code.

```
import cv2, Image, os


name = raw_input('Video File (With Extension): ')
x_res = int(raw_input('Image Width (Pixels): '))
y_res = int(raw_input('Image Height (Pixels): '))
rows = int(raw_input('Number of Rows: '))
columns = int(raw_input('Number of Columns: '))


vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
success,im = vidcap.read()
frames = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print frames
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_res, y_res))
x_cntr = 0
y_cntr = 0


if not os.path.exists('./' + name + ' Output/'):
    os.makedirs('./' + name + ' Output/')


for x in xrange(0,frames,1):
    if x%(rows*columns) == 0:
        new_im.save('./' + name + ' Output/' + str(x) + '.jpg')
        new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_res,y_res))
        y_cntr = 0
        x_cntr = 0
        print str(round(100*(float(x)/frames), 1)) + "% Complete"
    elif x%rows == 0:
        x_cntr = 0
        y_cntr = y_cntr + y_res/columns
    elif x%1 == 0:
        x_cntr = x_cntr + x_res/rows
    success,cv2_im = vidcap.read()
    if success == True:
        cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        im = Image.fromarray(cv2_im)
        im = im.resize((x_res/rows + x_res%rows, y_res/columns + y_res%columns), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        new_im.paste(im, (x_cntr, y_cntr))
    elif success == False:
        new_im.save('./' + name + ' Output/' + str(x) + '.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

This error suggests that your image cv2_im is not BGR format so it cannot convert to RGB. It must already be RGB format or might be GRAY format. The error represents format mismatch.

Use this code

```
cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

Comment: This didn't work. I found out my problem though. As I expected, it was trying to index something out of range. Basically, it was expecting 25 frames per image, but at the end, it got something less. So I added an `if success == True` statement within the `for` loop so that `if success == True` then do normal processing, but `if success == False` then just save what it has to a new image and stop.